# Regex not allowed Capital letter followed by lower case letters followed by number followed by special character

Tags: regex

regex need to match the below format

1. minimum 1 upper case
2. minimum 1 lower case
3. minimum 1 number case
4. minimum  1 special character

not allow More than two identical characters in a row

but we don't want to follow the specific below Patten(Initial cap word, followed by number, followed by special character- (e.g.,Fall2015!)) means upper case followed by lower case followed by number followed by special character

```
(?=.{8,24}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[_.!@$*=-?#])(([A-Za-z0-9_.!@$*=-?#])\2?(?!\2))
```

Comment: Sidenote `=-?` inside your character class is not finding a literal hyphen. Not sure if that's intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_.!@$*=?#-])(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?!.*[A-Z][a-z]+\d+[_.!@$*=?#-])[\w.!@$*=?#-]{8,24}$
```

The key changes are:

- `^` to anchor the expression to start
- `(?!.*(.)\1\1)` which prevents tripled chars
- `(?!.*[A-Z][a-z]+\d+[_.!@$*=?#-])` to prevent input like “Fall2015!”
- `[\w.!@$*=?#-]{8,24}$` to restrict input to only these chars and only 8-24 length
- Moving the hyphen to the end of the char class so it is a literal hyphen (not a range)

Note also the introduction of `\d` as shorthand for `[0-9]` and `\w` as shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: (?!.*[A-Z]) it's my mistake and i changed to (?=.*[A-Z]) . here we want to avoid the upper case flowed by lower case and lower case followed by  number and followed by special character(e.g Fall2015!) . is there a way to avoid above format